# Error when trying to copy a database from an elastic pool to another Azure server of mine

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm using CREATE DATABASE [DestDatabase] As COPY Of [ServerName].[SourceDatabase]

This works for every other database I try and copy but returns this error when I try and do it for database stored in a elastic pool.

"Elastic pool not found for server: 'DestinationServerName', elastic pool name: 'SourceElasticPoolName'."

It looks like it can't find the name of the Pool to add it to the destination server, but I can't find a way to specify which pool to added it to for the destination server. [ServerName].[ElasticName].[SourceDatabase] does not seem to be recognized as a command. Anyone know how to pick the pool name for the destination server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Both servers lie under the same subscription in your Azure Active Directory Tenant.